# find sum of largest X numbers using javascript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a list of five numbers echoed by php as demonstrated below:-

```
<div id="items">
<span class="number" id="one"><?php echo $one; //result = 1?> </span>

<span class="number" id="two"><?php echo $two; //result = 2?> </span>

<span class="number" id="three"><?php echo $three; //result = 3?> </span>

<span class="number" id="four"><?php echo $four; //result = 4?> </span>

<span class="number" id="five"><?php echo $five; //result = 5?> </span>

<div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to have a result of the best three scores displayed in the `<div id="result"></div>` div

For instance, in my question i would expect my result to be **12**

I there a simple way of doing this. probably with javascript or even PHP?

Comment: So you want **only** the highest number of those five numbers ?

Comment: so you want the sum of the best three?

Comment: @adeneo a sum of the best three numbers

Comment: @CodeGodie yes a sum of the best three.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where do `$one`, `$two`, etc. come from? Seems like this sum might be easier done before this point.

Comment: @dontpanic i fetch the numbers from the database where i am suppost to calculate result of the best three scores out of 5 scores. I will test the answers in the morning . I dint knw how to go about it after numerous efforts of googling. But atleast here i have found some answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $arr = array($one,$two,$three,$four,$five);
    arsort($arr);                    // sort descending, highest first
    $tre = array_slice($arr, 0, 3);  // first three
    $sum = array_sum($tre);          // summed up
?>

<div id="result"><?php echo $sum; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dump them into an array.  Sort the array.  Add up the top 3.

```
var nums =  [<? echo $one ?>,<? echo $two ?>,<? echo $three ?>,<? echo $four ?>,<? echo $five ?>]
nums.sort()
var resultIs = nums[2]+nums[3]+nums[4];

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = resultIs;
```

It's necessary to sort the array because you only want the 3 best.  This way you can send them in in any order, and you will easily find the ones you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
$nums = [$one, $two, $three, $four, $five];

sort($nums);
$last_three = array_slice($nums, -3);
$result = array_sum($last_three);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript only solution, no PHP

```
var sum = Array.prototype.map.call(
  document.querySelectorAll("span.number"),
  function(element) {
    return parseInt(element.innerHTML, 10);
  }
).sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a
}).slice(0,3).reduce(function(sum, newValue) {
    return sum + newValue
}, 0);

document.querySelector("div#result").innerHTML = sum;
```